# Merge to next populated cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to start at the top of a column and move down merging every empty cell until reaching the next cell with information in it. For example If I have "Step 1" in cell A1, cells A2 to A5 are empty and cell A6 contains "Step 2" I would want to merge A1 to A5.
Then if A22 contained "Step 3" and cells A7:A21 were empty, I would merge A6 to A21.

Really appreciate any assistance.
Thanks

Comment: Merged cells are a pain in the patoot and should be avoided. Use formatting. Draw a pretty border around the range instead. That way, you will still be able to select individual rows.

Comment: The cell(s) `.Interior.Color` (aka *Fill*) can be another method of visual identification without merging.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with the comments if you can avoid it don't merge them, make them look merged using a border; but if you must this will do what you were asking for:

```
   Dim cell As Range
   Dim StartCell As Range
   Dim EndCell As Range

   For Each cell In Range("a1", Range("a1000000").End(xlUp))
      If cell <> "" Then
         If StartCell Is Nothing Then
            Set StartCell = cell
         Else
            Set EndCell = cell.Offset(-1, 0)
            Range(StartCell, EndCell).Merge
            Set StartCell = cell
            Set EndCell = Nothing
         End If
      End If
   Next cell
```

Good Luck!